# C# group repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Is there a way to keep items in the same row based on their ID?

Just an example:

```
public class productInfo {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }

}

List<productInfo> products = new List<productInfo>();
   productInfo product = new productInfo {
       ID = "14",
       Type = "TypeOne",
       Size = "SizeTwo",
   };
products.Add(product);

Repeater.DataSource = products;
Repeater.DataBind();

 <td class="" style="">ID: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%></td>
```

There is a list that stores product information. In that list there are 10 entries. 3 of entries have the same ID and 2 of the entries have the same ID. The repeater should display 1 row with the 3 entries, 1 row with the 2 entries and 5 other rows. So basically every unique ID would gets it's own row.

[image]

In the picture, for example ID 3 I show the words "ID 3" three times. But I would only want to display "ID 3" once in the output.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide a mock-up of what you want to accomplish, that will give clear understanding

Comment: I added an image

Comment: A Repeater does not work that way, it just shows all the entries. You are better off building the HTML as a `string` or as a `Table` Control in code behind when dealing with all variable item numbers within a row.

Comment: @VDWWD Would you be able to provide me some example source code based on my situation?